# Regular expression to remove extra brackets in java

Tags: java, regex

I have data like below

```
 [[123,345,768]]
```

i want data as

```
 [123,345,768]
```

what is the regular expression in java i can use.?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just call `data.substring(1, data.length() - 1)`?

Comment: @Barend, that would be `-1`, second parameter is exclusive.

Comment: @Max yep, there was an off by one error in there (corrected now).

Comment: what if data is part of larger string ?

Comment: @Peeyush Quoting the original poster: `I have data like below [[123,345,768]]`

Comment: I'd like to mention that Regex is not able to handle bracket matching.. but if you're not matching the brackets then it'll be fine

Comment: @songyy: you have no idea what are you talking about

Comment: @mvp, he means that given the nested brackets like `(abc, (cde, def), sss)` there is no practical way to match each pair of brackets with regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str.replaceAll("\\[{2}(.*)\\]{2}", "[$1]");
```

[RegexPlanet demo](http://fiddle.re/hpm06)

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like that (with code sample):

```
"[[123,345,768]]".replaceAll("(\\[|\\])+", "$1"));
```

This one of course will remove all multiplicated brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
str.replaceAll("\\[(\\[[0-9,]+\\])\\])", "$1");
```

which throws away the outer brackets and keeps the inner, if that is still enclosed in brackets and contains only numbers and comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String replaced = str.replaceAll("([]\\[]){2,}", "$1");
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/oypyyr